# Rewrite image paths in Grunt

Tags: html, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I'm searching for a "catch-all" Grunt task to rewrite my html's image paths based on the production or dev environment. I've looked into usemin and filerev - but I'm having trouble understanding what exactly to do.

Is there anything I can use to change the following...

```
<img src="/img/template/banner.jpg" />
```

to this:

```
<img src"/some-other-path-here/banner.jpg />
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grunt-usemin isn't the task for this particular job, it is meant to automate the concatenation, minification, and revving of your scripts and styles in a single step. There are several "CDN" tasks that will help you with changing relative paths:

- https://github.com/callumlocke/grunt-cdnify
- https://github.com/tactivos/grunt-cdn

Comment: Ah nice. Thanks for that, xiwcx! :)

Answer (score 1):

it can be done in usemin

```
patterns: {
                js: [
                    [/(img\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm,'Update the JS to reference our revved images',function(match){
return .... <-- you can replace it to whatever you want here.
```

}